# What's the origin of using "toboggan" to mean a knit cap?

Tags: etymology

I'd always know the word "toboggan" to mean a sled. In the last couple years I've met people who insisted on calling their winter knit caps "toboggans." All of these people happened to be from either Kentucky or Tennessee.  [Wikipedia mentions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toboggan_%28hat%29) that

> In the United States south and midwest, especially Appalachia, it is often called a "toboggan".

but there's no info about origin. When and where did this usage come from?

Comment: The southern states call them toboggans. I am not quite sure the reason. I am from NC. My dad, from Wisconsin, insisted toboggans were sleds.

Comment: I am from Arkansas, and my husband calls them tobogans. I call them bogans.

Comment: I like to wear my toboggan at the beach sporting a speedo, I call it speedbogganing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=toboggan) lists this shift in the late 20's, probably because it's the type of cap you would wear while tobagganing. I imagine it was probably first called a "toboggan cap", and then eventually the "cap" was just dropped.

Answer (score 4):

Chris's intuition is confirmed by the OED, which lists "toboggan-cap" among similar compound formations as "toboggan-bag" and "toboggan-chute".